# How do I add a resource folder to app data?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a folder that contains many png images in my resources of my WPF application. I would like to add this folder to appdata/roaming. Since there are many images that are sorted in folders, I would prefer to add the whole folder. Is there any way to do this?

By the way, the folder is in a directory called Resources and all the pngs are build as resources in Visual Studio.

Comment: [How to: Copy directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories)

Comment: Why would you want to add *resources* to a folder in Windows? The resources are compiled into your assembly.

Comment: I think what you really mean is "Assets" not "Resources" - in terms of common naming convention in WPF. Like @mm8 said, you usually compile resources into your application. If you don't want to do it and want to have let's say images as files, they are usually called assets. But then - if they are strictly related to the app, use in-assembly resources, if they are dynamic, created or uploaded by users - then by all means - put them in `AppData` special folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code example for your question:

```
 public void MyCopy()
    {
        //1.You can use the following code to get the path appdata/roaming, and suppose you want to copy the files to NewImageFolder
        string strTarget = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).ToString() + "\\NewImageFolder\\";
        if (!Directory.Exists(strTarget))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strTarget);
        }

        //2. Then you need to get the path of your the File to be copied
        string strSource = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        strSource = strSource.Substring(0, strSource.LastIndexOf("bin")) + "Resources\\Image";

        //3.Copy the file       
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(strSource);
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        string strFileName = null;
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            strFileName = strSource + "\\" + file.Name;
            File.Copy(strFileName, System.IO.Path.Combine(strTarget, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName)));
        }
    }
```